# Removing image from SharePoint 2010 Search Result

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

We have a requirement to remove image files from SharePoint search results. For example if we uploaded an file called **SharePointDiagram.png** to a SharePoint document library, we don't want this file to show up in Search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to go into central admin and create search exclusion rules for the image types you no longer want to index.

```
*://*.png*
```

You can go into the File Types section and remove them there if they exist to achieve the same effect.